# Unable to login with SCP using ppk file

Tags: linux, ssh

I need it to connect to a linux server form a windows using a `.ppk` file to connect.

The steps are:

1. Generate a `id_rsa` key in server linux using `ssh-keygen.`
2. Copy the `id_rsa` file to a windows machine with PYTTUgen.
3. Import the `id_rsa` and export the private key (`.ppk`)
4. Try to login with winSCP selecting the generated `.ppk` file.
5. In linux server tail the secure log and:

   ```
   No supported authentication methods available [preauth]
   ```

What's wrong?

I have another user configured using this method and it works correctly.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you append the public key to your `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file (on the server)?

The public key is in `id_rsa.pub`

By the way, it's more secure to generate your key pair on your local machine, and then append the public key to the servers `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks both, finally I solved the problem. The solution was to change directory permissions on /home/username to 700 and done!!

Thanks so much!